# Show context menu only if variable is true

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have this piece of code in my .xaml file:

```
  <Window.Resources>
  <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
        <MenuItem Header="Blokiraj" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Deblokiraj" Click="MenuItem2_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="-------------"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Sakrij" Click="MenuItem3_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Prikaži" Click="MenuItem4_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="dxe:CheckEdit">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="dx:SimpleButton">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="dxb:BarCheckItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="dxb:BarSubItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    </Style>
   </Window.Resources>
```

This context menu should be shown on every control on my window only if I enter administration mode which is defined by a single boolean value. That boolean value is Globals.admin = True/False.

So if I define Globals.admin = false then context menu "cm" should not be shown, because it interferes with my other context menus which are different for every control on my form.

Comment: Do you have a ViewModel? The Global variables is in a Notifiable ViewModel to allow you to do the change and impact the UI on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I did not know exactly your projects particularities, but I think the following code will help you.

xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
        <MenuItem Header="Blokiraj"  />
        <MenuItem Header="Deblokiraj" />
        <MenuItem Header="-------------"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Sakrij" />
        <MenuItem Header="Prikaži" />
    </ContextMenu>

    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="ControlWithContextMenuStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Globals.admin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ControlWithContextMenuStyle}"
            Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click"
            Width="100" Height="50"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

the code behind the xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GlobalsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Globals", typeof(GlobalVariables), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public GlobalVariables Globals
    {
        get { return (GlobalVariables)GetValue(GlobalsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GlobalsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Globals = new GlobalVariables();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.admin = true;
    }
}
```

and the GlobalVariables class:

```
  public class GlobalVariables : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Boolean _admin;

    public Boolean admin
    {
        get { return _admin; }
        set
        {
            _admin = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("admin");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

The Framework Element style could be useful for your to make only one style that then can be inherited wherever you need it. You can change the way the Binding is done in the style, to correspond to your projects needs.